# Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) while testing php website forms

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

When i test any forms of my php website at local host i get the below meassage...

```
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

We use phpmyadmin as backend...
plz suggest the solution.
```

Answer (score 0):

That is a database related error.  Your script is trying to access the database as root which is denied on your system.  Check your database connection user/password credentials.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
     $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
     if (!$link) {
       die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
     }
     echo 'Connected successfully';
     mysql_close($link);
?>
```

There are more available parameters, but the ones listed above are the most important.

Comment: i checked the database connection....each thing is right. but i read in blogs That error means that a webpage is accessing a server that has a password, but is not using one. root@localhost has a password and probably your mysql_connect() doesn't have a password parameter set up. But i dont know how to resolve it so please suggest the solution for the same